# Use of uninitialised value of size 8 from valgrind in c

Tags: arrays, c, memory, dynamic, valgrind

As Valgrind gives line numbers in the error summary, I'll provide the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int n = 0;
int q = 0;
int Z = 0;
scanf("%i %i", &n, &q);
fgetc(stdin);
int seqList[n][n];
int lastAnswer = 0;
char *queries[q];
int *index = malloc((sizeof(int) * n));          // Line 14
int *last = malloc(sizeof(int) * q);
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
{
    queries[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", queries[i]);

    if (queries[i][0] == '1')
    {
        int x = queries[i][2] - '0';
        int y = queries[i][4] - '0';
        int z = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n;
        Z = *(index + z);
        seqList[z][Z] = y;                       // Line 27
        *(index + z) = Z + 1;
    }
    else if (queries[i][0] == '2')
    {
        int x = queries[i][2] - '0';
        int y = queries[i][4] - '0';
        int z = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n;
        Z = *(index + z);
        lastAnswer = seqList[z][y % Z]; //floating point exception
        last[k] = lastAnswer;
        k++;
    }
    free(queries[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    printf("%i\n", last[i]);
}
free(last);
free(index);
}
```

When I run the program, on my second input (after providing the values of n and q), I get this error message:

```
==9541== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==9541==    at 0x4008FA: main (dynamic.c:27)
==9541==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==9541==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind    /vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9541==    by 0x40080B: main (dynamic.c:14)
==9541==
```

Lines 27 and line 14 are highlighted with with comments; I tried implementing this in many ways but couldn't understand what it means by the "uninitialized" value.

Comment: Maybe try `calloc(n, sizeof (type))`

Comment: Remove these `***`, they make your code invalid. Add relevcant comments instead.

Comment: "uninitialized" value means that the value is not initialized.

Comment: Your `// line27` comment is actually in line 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line(s):

```c
    Z = *(index + z);
```

you are, on *at least* one occasion, reading a value from the `index` memory block that has not *yet* had a value assigned to it. (Incidentally, you can use `Z = index[z]` for clearer code.) So, the value of that 'array element' will be uninitialized.

I'm not sure what initial values you want/need to assign to that `index` array but, as suggested in the comments, you can use the [`calloc()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) to set all elements to zero at the time of allocation (note that the [`malloc()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) creates a block of *uninitialized* data).

So, instead of:

```c
int* index = malloc((sizeof(int) * n));
```

use:

```c
int* index = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: can there be a floating point exception on the mentioned line, (% operator and none of the operands are zero).

Comment: @Musical_Ant If `Z` has garbage value assigned, then using it as index (or to calculat index) into `seqList` can cause segfault or a division by zero exception.